# roslibjs does not receive message containing sensor_msgs/CompressedImage field

Tags: ros, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to create the custom message encapsulating several `sensor_msgs/CompressedImage` fields. I planned to connect it with `roslibjs` to display the images on the webpage. But the web application does not receive anything. Actually, I cannot even to catch the message receiving event. The message type is set up correctly. The publisher is saying the following:

```
[WARN] [1633447998.427242]: Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details
```

Message structure:

```
Header header
sensor_msgs/CompressedImage raw_frame
sensor_msgs/CompressedImage annotated_frame
sensor_msgs/CompressedImage depth_map
bool has_detections
roi[] detections
```

where `roi` is another custom message. When I am trying to pass just `sensor_msgs/CompressedImage` everything works. Could you please help me to investigate why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388000/roslibjs-does-not-receive-message-containing-sensor_msgs/compressedimage-field/) by [twdragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40258/twdragon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2021-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to specify the correct package name for the `detections` field, just like you did with `CompressedImage`. There was likely an error message telling you this message type failed to compile.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1